# How to correctly implement validation when training using Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

there. I want to validate my neural network during the process of training. 
A placeholder is created to decide whether train_batch or test_batch should be feed into the network to realize validation.
Here is my sample code. In the **train.tfrecords**, the number is from 0 to 100, and in the **test.tfrecords**, it is from 200 to 240.

```
create_tfrecord(filename=r'test', begin_num=200, end_num=240)

filename = r'./train.tfrecords'
filename_que = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename],
                                              num_epochs=1)
num = decode_tfrecord(filename_que)

testfilename = r'./test.tfrecords'
test_que = tf.train.string_input_producer([testfilename],
                                          num_epochs=None)
test_num = decode_tfrecord(test_que)

is_training = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.bool, shape=())

num = tf.cond(is_training, lambda:num, lambda:test_num)    

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()

init_op = tf.local_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init_op)
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord, sess=sess)

    try:
        i = 0
        while not coord.should_stop():

            feed_dict = {is_training: True}
            number = sess.run(num, feed_dict=feed_dict)
            print("global_step: %i, read_num: %i" %(i, number))

            if i % 5 == 0 and i != 0:
                feed_dict = {is_training: False}
                number = sess.run(num, feed_dict=feed_dict)
                print("global_step: %i, read_num: %i" %(i, number))

            i += 1


    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print("done.")

    finally:
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

However, the output is not fully the same as what i want. The test_batch is not begin from 200 that is the first number in **test.tfrecords** rather than begin from 206. After that, the train_batch is begin from 7 rather than 6. Here is some outputs.

```
global_step: 0, read_num: 0
global_step: 1, read_num: 1
global_step: 2, read_num: 2
global_step: 3, read_num: 3
global_step: 4, read_num: 4
global_step: 5, read_num: 5
global_step: 5, read_num: 206
global_step: 6, read_num: 7
global_step: 7, read_num: 8
global_step: 8, read_num: 9
global_step: 9, read_num: 10
global_step: 10, read_num: 11
global_step: 10, read_num: 212
```

Those outputs acts like **there exists a counter which is used both in training and validation.** Once the epochs is set to 1, not all my training set could be used in the training stage, and the order my test_batch be fetched is not what i want. I think this way is a wrong way to realize validation when training.

So, is there anyone could tell me how can i correctly implement validating during training my network?

Thanks in advance.